# Colpick.js pallet size

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-palette

I am using colpick.js to get a color pallet. It is working fine. But default size of the pallet is not enough for me. How can i expand it a little bit. Can someone give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Go to colorpicker.css and find .colorpicker
 and change height and width as needed

```
.colorpicker {
      width: 356px;
     height: 176px;
     overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
     background: url(../images/colorpicker_background.png);
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: none;
  }
```

Comment: It changed the size of the box. Slider and color color box inside. they dont change. Is there any property  given by the library to do this?

Comment: Find #colorSelector2  in html change inline height